# How to add a watermark to the saved video with CameraX api in saving time

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using the CameraX api approach to record the videos and saving them as explained in the documents: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/video-capture
I tried with [ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) but clearly it needs to process the saved video not adding to the saved frames in real time.  
 
Now, I want to add a watermark to all saved videos in easy and not costly way and without the need to reprocess the video?
Also, if there is no way, what the best and fastest approach to process the video to only add a watermark?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you need to write a player-like code that uses opengles to draw videos so you can add your own arbitrary watermark. Or use the cross-compiled ffmepg dynamic library (or static library) to add your own filters.

Answer (score 0):

I shared an example of cross-compiled ffmpeg on github. Is to implement a player that can play video. Check it out [here](https://github.com/bboywindy/AndroidExample).

I hope you got some help.